# Can an infinite product of recursive functions be non-recursive?

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, recursion

Suppose you have a finite product of recursive functions (e.g. primitive recursive). The result function will be primitive recursive.

But what if we count the infinite product of primitive recursive functions. Will the product be recursive or non-recursive?

Comment: What does it even mean to take an infinite product of primitive recursive functions?

Comment: The unbounded multiplication of primitive recursive functions.

Comment: Right, but what does “unbounded multiplication” mean?

Comment: @MarkSaving This seems like a benign issue since recursiveness applies to *partial* functions: given an arbitrary sequence of partial functions $(p_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$, let $\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}p_i(x)$ be undefined if any $p_i(x)$ is undefined or if that product is infinite, and be defined with the obvious value otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, any infinitary operation on functions need not preserve recursiveness.

In this particular case, let $f_i(x)=1$ if $x$ did not enter the halting problem at stage $i$ exactly, and let $f_i(x)=2$ if $x$ has entered the halting problem at stage $i$ exactly. Then the $f_i$s are (even *uniformly*) recursive, but the infinite product $$p:x\mapsto\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}f_i(x)$$ is Turing-equivalent to the halting problem: $x$ is in the halting problem iff $p(x)=2$.